# Arquillian testing JSF with CDI - CDI Scope issue

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi, jsf-2.2, jboss-arquillian

We are in the process of migrating our JavaEE app from Weblogic 10.3.6 to Weblogic 12.2.1.2.  As part of this migration we are changing our JSF managaged beans to use CDI annotations rather than the standard JSF annotations. `@ManagedBean` to `@Named` and `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` to `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`.  This has proved successful with only minor issues.  However I am having a big issue trying to get our tests to run. The tests fail with the following error:

```
WebBeans context with scope type annotation @ViewScoped does not exist within current thread
```

I have tried multiple different containers (embedded and remote) but still get this same error.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I am using Arquillian with the following pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.12.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-openejb-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

BackingBean:

```
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AnotherBean implements Serializable {

    public String doTest()
    {
        System.out.println("test");
        return "test";
    }
}
```

TestBean

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestAgain  {

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
                .addClass(AnotherBean.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Inject
    AnotherBean anotherBean;

    @Test
    public void doTest()
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(anotherBean.doTest(), "test");
        anotherBean.doTest();
    }
}
```

UPDATE

If I change the @Deployment to:

```
@Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.jar")
                .addClass(AnotherBean.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }
```

I Get:

```
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [AnotherBean] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  anotherBean, Bean Owner : [null]
```

Answer (score 0):

We hat similar difficulties in testing @ViewScoped beans. We solved this by creating the bean with its injections in the test ourselfs.

The Bean instance itself ist created in the test and all dependencies are then inserted into that by using reflection. This works with beans, entitymanger etc

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ViewControllerTest {
@Inject private OtherBean otherBean;

private ViewController viewController;


@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
  return WebArchiveFactory.getDefaultWebarchArchive();
}

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
  viewController = new ViewController();
  TestHelper.setFacesContext(); // provide FacesContextMock
  TestHelper.inject(viewController, "otherBean", otherBean);
}
}
```

With TestHelper looking like this

```
public class TestHelper {

public static void inject(Object bean, 
                          String fieldName, 
                          Object fieldValue) throws Exception {
  if (null == bean) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bean must not be null");
  }
  Field field;
  try {
    field = bean.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not find field for injection: " + fieldName);
    throw e;
  }
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.set(bean, fieldValue);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to work around this problem with a good old fashioned hack.  I found the source for `org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl` where the original `WebBeans context with scope type annotation @ViewScoped does not exist within current thread` comes from.  I created this class within my test sources and I then made some changes to get around the problem.

Ultimately for my tests I don't care about the scope.  I'm testing that the methods run and return the correct logic/data.  So in the class it goes and checks what type of scope the bean is in and throws the exception.  I simply checked if it was in `Viewscoped` and if so changed it to `Dependent`.  This then allowed my tests to work.

Not the best solution but it works.